# Insert into SQL table only for records with no entry

Tags: sql-server, insert, notin

I have two tables:

1. `cSc_user`: here is every user stored. PK is camosGUID
2. `cSc_UserRole`: when a user has a role, a row for this user is stored here

For every role the user has, there is one entry in `cSc_userRole`. FK for `camosGUID` in this table is `UserGUID`. There is also a column `RoleGUID`. I want only consider one role which has the `RoleGUID = AD3BB`.

Now my target is to create a record in `cSc_UserRole` for every user who doesn't have an entry for the role with the `RoleGuid = AD3BB`. Additionally I want to exclude two users with the `camosGUID = -1` and `2032`.

This is what I've done already. The problem is it creates an entry in `cSc_UserRole` also if the user has already the role. So it's duplicated after running the query.

```
INSERT INTO [csc_userrole] ([RSRC], [Deleted], [DateNew], [DateChanged],
                            [UserNew], [UserChanged], [camosGUID],
                            [UserGUID], [RoleGUID])
    SELECT
        0, 0, GETDATE(), GETDATE(),
        2032, 2032, NEWID(),
        camosGUID, 'AD3BB'
    FROM 
        [cSc_User] 
    WHERE 
        csc_user.camosguid <> -1 
        AND csc_user.camosguid <> 2032 
        AND (csc_user.camosguid NOT IN (SELECT userguid
                                        FROM cSc_Userrole) OR 
             csc_user.camosguid IN (SELECT userguid
                                    FROM cSc_Userrole
                                    WHERE roleguid <> 'AD3BB' 
                                      AND roleguid <> 'E5DEE'))
```

Comment: It's totally wrong to store status of record's relation as a column in itself. You can create a view for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query below would return the users you are looking for. I would leave this in a view.

```
select * 
from cSc_user
where
   --users that don't have a role of AD3BB
   UserGUID not in (select UserGUID from cSc_user where RoleGUID = 'AD3BB')
   --the camosGUIDs you want to exclude
   and camosGUID  not in (-1,2032)
```

So, in a view...

```
create view myUserList
as
select * 
from cSc_user
where
   --users that don't have a role of AD3BB
   UserGUID not in (select UserGUID from cSc_user where RoleGUID = 'AD3BB')
   --the camosGUIDs you want to exclude
   and camosGUID  not in (-1,2032)
```

Then query from it...

```
select * from myUserList
```

Comment: I should note that it’s bad practice to use SELECT * in a view.